# "time vs. times" when referring to the current COVID-19 incidence?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

An easy google search shows both "**time**" and "**times**" are used in describing the current COVID-19 pandemic.

Is there any difference?

- [Resources You Can Use in **These Unusual Times** from the National
  Initiative for Consumer Horticulture](https://www.perishablenews.com/floral/resources-you-can-use-in-these-unusual-times-from-the-national-initiative-for-consumer-horticulture/)
- [In **these unusual times**, Aditro is of course continuously
  monitoring the situation regarding the coronavirus (covid-19) in all
  Nordic countries.](https://aditro.com/news/measures-taken-regarding-the-coronavirus-covid-19/)
- [UL remains open for business and committed to serving your needs in
  **this unusual time**](https://www.ul.com/news/ul-covid-19-response)
- [... providing some guidance on how to navigate relationships in
  **this unusual time**](https://psychology.msu.edu/news-events/news/covid19-maintainrelationships-chopik.html)

Comment: Times is generally more historical. time isn't  necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, there is no difference.

[American Heritage Dictionary "time"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=time)

2.
**a.** (often *times*) An interval, especially a span of years, marked by similar events, conditions, or phenomena; an era: hard times; a time of troubles.
**b.** *times* The present with respect to prevailing conditions and trends: You must change with the times.

If you were talking about a difficult period for a family because of the death of a family member, you would probably use the singular: "a difficult time".

If you were talking about a period of decades of change in industrial technology, you would probably use the plural: "interesting times".

However, for most uses, you could use either "time" or "times".